# How to have multiple hyperlinks on the same line for a navbar

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to create a navbar for my site and I want to have multiple headers with links please help. I can't figure out if it's my css thats messed up or both that and my html.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>WalletPro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id="navbar">
            <nav>
                <div id="main-head">
                    <h1> <a href="index.html"> Home </a></h1>
                </div>
                <div id="login"><a href="login.html"> login</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#navbar{
  display: inline;
}

#navbar{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background-color: #f011f0;
}

#test {
  color: pink;
  text-emphasis: none;
}
```

Comment: There are different ways. You could set `#navbar div { display: inline-block }`, use flexbox or even float

Comment: `header` tag should be inside `body` tag.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways you could simplify both your HTML and CSS:

- Since the navbar is the only thing in your header, there's no need for the header tag
- The `nav` element is already `display: block;` by default, so there's no need for the extra div element
- Remove the `div` and `h1` elements within the `nav` element since it's not [semantic](https://www.semrush.com/blog/semantic-html5-guide/) and these are block level elements
- And instead, use the a nested list to hold navigation links

Here's How The Improved HTML Might Look:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.html" id="main-head">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="login.html">Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

As for the CSS:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #f011f0;
}

#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#main-head {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

This is one way to make your links display on the same line with code that's simple and semantic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).